# Python pandas groupby correlation includes all columns instead of selected columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
a b c g
0 0.273411 -0.573347 -0.411541 group1
1 -1.068101 -0.987671 1.501582 group1
2 0.784626 0.003757 -0.938192 group1
3 0.221111 0.480360 0.546703 group1
4 1.277762 -1.285070 -0.415170 group1
5 1.870870 1.320776 -1.628251 group1
6 -0.158213 1.317783 1.803866 group2
7 -1.193541 -2.841256 -0.784413 group2
8 -1.242116 0.037265 -0.888934 group2
9 -0.782190 0.678842 -0.127150 group2

10 rows × 4 columns 

In [28]: df.groupby('g')[['a', 'b']].mean()
Out[28]: 
        a      b
g
group1 0.559947 -0.173533
group2 -0.844015 -0.201841

2 rows × 2 columns 

In [29]: df.groupby('g')[['a', 'b']].corr()
Out[29]: 

a  b  c
g
group1
a  1.000000  0.490017 -0.919512
b  0.490017  1.000000 -0.526212
c  -0.919512 -0.526212 1.000000
group2
a 1.000000 0.696526 0.988657
b 0.696526 1.000000 0.652678
c 0.988657 0.652678 1.000000

6 rows × 3 columns 

In [30]:
```

As shown, when calculating correlation matrix by group, pandas ignores that I only want to calculate correlations between columns `a` and `b` and calculates correlations for all columns. Is this a bug?

Comment: yep...being addressed in this issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5264 (feel free to help out if you can!)

Comment: To be honest, I wish I could help but I don't think I qualify...